# Profiles deployment & Ant

Tags: deployment, ant

This may be a noob question but please point me in the right direction. I'm interested to know how does the profile object is deployed so that it doesn't overwrite the parts that are not deployed.

For example, if I retrieve profiles with APEX only. Then I edit this file and deploy it, why it doesn't remove all the other parts like object and field permissions that I didn't retrieve?

Thank you,

Comment: Not specifically related to profiles, but I recommend you migrate to using either [sfdx](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) or the new unified [sf](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/06/announcing-salesforce-cli-unification) CLI rather than ant. The ant targets are no longer developed. Using these doesn't stop you creating ant scripts, though you will need to use ant's exec task to run CLI operations.

Comment: Because deployments are additive in nature and not other way around when you are deploying profiles with only limited information like Apex Class access rest of the details will stay as it is. If you want to change everything you will have to actually retrieve all objects , fields etc along with profiles then deploy it.